# Incorrect date value: '' for column 'DATESORTIE' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

In a spring form i'm adding a new employe that has the date that he begin the work and the date that he left the company and the problem that i have is when an employe is unil now working in company the dae that he left the company should be null. but when i don't touch the date field tomcat gives me the error :

```
Incorrect date value: '' for column 'DATESORTIE' at row 1
```

**this is my *Employee.hbm.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 5 ao?t 2015 11:05:44 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.my.dao.Employe" table="EMPLOYE">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomEmploye" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NOMEMPLOYE" />
        </property>
        <property name="prenomEmploye" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PRENOMEMPLOYE" />
        </property>
        <property name="matriculeMY" type="int">
            <column name="MATRICULEMY" />
        </property>
        <property name="adresse" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ADRESSE" />
        </property>
        <property name="sexe" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SEXE" />
        </property>
        <property name="cin" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CIN" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateNaissance" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATENAISSANCE" />
        </property>
        <property name="situationFamiliale" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SITUATIONFAMILIALE" />
        </property>
<!--         <property name="nbEnfant" type="int">
            <column name="NBENFANT"></column>
        </property> -->
        <property name="dateEntree" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATEENTREE" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateSortie" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATESORTIE" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCIMR" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCIMR" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCNSS" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCNSS" />
        </property>
        <property name="numMUT" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMMUT" />
        </property>
        <property name="profile" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PROFILE" />
        </property>
        <property name="resteConge" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="RESTECONGE" />
        </property>
        <property name="banque" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="BANQUE" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCpteBanc" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCPTEBANC" />
        </property>
        <property name="fonction" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FONCTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="salaire" type="float">
            <column name="SALAIRE" />
        </property>
        <property name="indTransport" type="float">
            <column name="INDTRANSPORT" />
        </property>
        <property name="indRepresent" type="float">
            <column name="INDREPRESENT" />
        </property>
        <property name="indPanier" type="float">
            <column name="INDPANIER" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="eDepartement" class="com.my.dao.Departement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EDEPARTEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eFonction" class="com.my.dao.Fonction" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EFONCTION" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eService" class="com.my.dao.Service" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="ESERVICE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eTypePaiement" class="com.my.dao.TypePaiement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="ETYPEPAIEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eModePaiement" class="com.my.dao.ModePaiement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EMODEPAIEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**this is my *com.my.dao.Employee* class**

```
package com.my.dao;

/**
 * @author Ilias
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Employe {

private int id;
private String nomEmploye;
private String prenomEmploye;
private int matriculeMY;
private String adresse;
private String sexe;
private String cin;
private String dateNaissance;
private String situationFamiliale;
private int nbEnfant;
private String dateEntree;
private String dateSortie;
private String numCIMR;
private String numCNSS;
private String numMUT;
private String profile;
private String resteConge;
private String banque;
private String numCpteBanc;
private String fonction;
private float salaire;
private float indTransport;
private float indRepresent;
private float indPanier;
private Departement eDepartement;
private Fonction eFonction;
private Service eService;
private TypePaiement eTypePaiement;
private ModePaiement eModePaiement;

/**
 * @return the nbEnfant
 */
public int getNbEnfant() {
    return nbEnfant;
}


/**
 * @param nbEnfant the nbEnfant to set
 */
public void setNbEnfant(int nbEnfant) {
    this.nbEnfant = nbEnfant;
}


public String getAdresse() {
return adresse;
}


public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
this.adresse = adresse;
}

public Departement getM_Departement() {
return eDepartement;
}


public void setM_Departement(Departement m_Departement) {
this.eDepartement = m_Departement;
}


public Fonction getM_Fonction() {
return eFonction;
}


public void setM_Fonction(Fonction m_Fonction) {
this.eFonction = m_Fonction;
}


public Service getM_Service() {
return eService;
}


public void setM_Service(Service m_Service) {
this.eService = m_Service;
}


public TypePaiement getM_TypePaiement() {
return eTypePaiement;
}


public void setM_TypePaiement(TypePaiement m_TypePaiement) {
this.eTypePaiement = m_TypePaiement;
}


public ModePaiement getM_ModePaiement() {
return eModePaiement;
}


public void setM_ModePaiement(ModePaiement m_ModePaiement) {
this.eModePaiement = m_ModePaiement;
}


public int getId() {
return id;
}


public String getBanque() {
return banque;
}


public void setBanque(String banque) {
this.banque = banque;
}


public String getNumCpteBanc() {
return numCpteBanc;
}


public void setNumCpteBanc(String numCpteBanc) {
this.numCpteBanc = numCpteBanc;
}


public float getSalaire() {
return salaire;
}


public void setSalaire(float salaire) {
this.salaire = salaire;
}


public float getIndTransport() {
return indTransport;
}


public void setIndTransport(float indTransport) {
this.indTransport = indTransport;
}


public float getIndRepresent() {
return indRepresent;
}


public void setIndRepresent(float indRepresent) {
this.indRepresent = indRepresent;
}


public float getIndPanier() {
return indPanier;
}


public void setIndPanier(float indPanier) {
this.indPanier = indPanier;
}


public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}


public String getNomEmploye() {
return nomEmploye;
}

public void setNomEmploye(String nomEmploye) {
this.nomEmploye = nomEmploye;
}

public String getPrenomEmploye() {
return prenomEmploye;
}

public void setPrenomEmploye(String prenomEmploye) {
this.prenomEmploye = prenomEmploye;
}

public int getMatriculeMY() {
return matriculeMY;
}

public void setMatriculeMY(int matriculeMY) {
this.matriculeMY = matriculeMY;
}

public String getSexe() {
return sexe;
}

public void setSexe(String sexe) {
this.sexe = sexe;
}

public String getCin() {
return cin;
}

public void setCin(String cin) {
this.cin = cin;
}

public String getDateNaissance() {
    return dateNaissance;
}

public void setDateNaissance(String dateNaissance) {
this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
}

public String getSituationFamiliale() {
return situationFamiliale;
}

public void setSituationFamiliale(String situationFamiliale) {
this.situationFamiliale = situationFamiliale;
}

public String getDateEntree() {
return dateEntree;
}

public void setDateEntree(String dateEntree) {
this.dateEntree = dateEntree;
}

public String getDateSortie() {
return dateSortie;
}

public void setDateSortie(String dateSortie) {
this.dateSortie = dateSortie;
}

public String getNumCIMR() {
return numCIMR;
}

public void setNumCIMR(String numCIMR) {
this.numCIMR = numCIMR;
}

public String getNumCNSS() {
return numCNSS;
}

public void setNumCNSS(String numCNSS) {
this.numCNSS = numCNSS;
}

public String getNumMUT() {
return numMUT;
}

public void setNumMUT(String numMUT) {
this.numMUT = numMUT;
}

public String getProfile() {
return profile;
}

public void setProfile(String profile) {
this.profile = profile;
}

public String getResteConge() {
return resteConge;
}

public void setResteConge(String resteConge) {
this.resteConge = resteConge;
}


public void copie(Employe e)
{

this.nomEmploye = e.nomEmploye;

System.out.println("nom : "+e.getNomEmploye()+"  nom :"+this.nomEmploye);

this.prenomEmploye = e.prenomEmploye;
this.matriculeMY = e.matriculeMY;
this.sexe = e.sexe;
this.cin = e.cin;
this.dateNaissance = e.dateNaissance;
this.situationFamiliale = e.situationFamiliale;
this.dateEntree = e.dateEntree;
this.dateSortie = e.dateSortie;
this.numCIMR = e.numCIMR;
this.numCNSS = e.numCNSS;
this.numMUT = e.numMUT;
this.profile = e.profile;
this.resteConge = e.resteConge;
this.banque = e.banque;
this.numCpteBanc = e.numCpteBanc;
this.salaire = e.salaire;
this.indTransport = e.indTransport;
this.indRepresent = e.indRepresent;
this.indPanier = e.indPanier;
this.fonction = e.fonction;
this.eDepartement = e.eDepartement;
this.eFonction = e.eFonction;
this.eService = e.eService;
this.eTypePaiement = e.eTypePaiement;
this.eModePaiement = e.eModePaiement;

}


public Employe(Employe e){
this.nomEmploye = e.nomEmploye;

System.out.println("nom : "+e.getNomEmploye()+"  nom :"+this.nomEmploye);

this.setNomEmploye(e.nomEmploye);
this.setPrenomEmploye(e.prenomEmploye);
this.setCin(e.cin);
this.setDateNaissance(e.dateNaissance);
this.setSituationFamiliale(e.situationFamiliale);
this.setDateEntree(e.dateEntree);
this.setDateSortie(e.dateSortie);
this.setNumCIMR(e.numCIMR);
this.setNumCNSS(e.numCNSS);
this.setNumMUT(e.numMUT);
this.setProfile(e.profile);
this.setResteConge(e.resteConge);
this.setBanque(e.banque);
this.setNumCpteBanc(e.numCpteBanc);
this.setSalaire(e.salaire);
this.setIndTransport(e.indTransport);
this.setIndRepresent(e.indRepresent);
this.setIndPanier(e.indPanier);
this.setFonction(e.fonction);
this.setM_Departement(e.eDepartement);

}



public String getFonction() {
    return fonction;
}


public void setFonction(String fonction) {
    this.fonction = fonction;
}


public Employe(String nomEmploye, String prenomEmploye, int matriculeMY, String adresse, String sexe, String cin,
        String dateNaissance, String situationFamiliale, String dateEntree, String dateSortie, String numCIMR,
        String numCNSS, String numMUT, String profile, String resteConge, String banque, String numCpteBanc,
        String fonction, int salaire, float indTransport, float indRepresent, float indPanier,
        Departement m_Departement, Fonction m_Fonction, Service m_Service, TypePaiement m_TypePaiement,
        ModePaiement m_ModePaiement) {
super();
this.nomEmploye = nomEmploye;
this.prenomEmploye = prenomEmploye;
this.matriculeMY = matriculeMY;
this.adresse = adresse;
this.sexe = sexe;
this.cin = cin;
this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
this.situationFamiliale = situationFamiliale;
this.dateEntree = dateEntree;
this.dateSortie = dateSortie;
this.numCIMR = numCIMR;
this.numCNSS = numCNSS;
this.numMUT = numMUT;
this.profile = profile;
this.resteConge = resteConge;
this.banque = banque;
this.numCpteBanc = numCpteBanc;
this.fonction = fonction;
this.salaire = salaire;
this.indTransport = indTransport;
this.indRepresent = indRepresent;
this.indPanier = indPanier;
this.eDepartement = m_Departement;
this.eFonction = m_Fonction;
this.eService = m_Service;
this.eTypePaiement = m_TypePaiement;
this.eModePaiement = m_ModePaiement;
}


public Employe() {

}


/** 
 * {@exception} Throwable 
 */

public void finalize() throws Throwable{

}
}
```

I'm working with Spring using SpringMVC,hibernate(hbm files),MYSQL DB

**PLZ, can some one help ?**

Comment: You should show the Java code that is building the DB statement and failing at processing it. Clearly, you are inserting an empty string instead of `null`.

Comment: What type of column is DATESORTIE? Ensure that it is nullable, and in your Java class, ensure that the value is null when not set. This looks like you are attempting to store an empty string instead of null.

Comment: can you show the hbm file for the Employee and the stack trace of the error ?

Comment: @NickJ type of column DATESORTIE is Date but in java class is String

Comment: Why String? I suggest using a Date in java as well. Please post code (Employee class) and your hbm config.

Comment: @ShadowRay i update the question

Comment: @NickJ i added Employe class and Employe hbm file

Comment: @yb3prod what is the type of column `DATESORTIE` in you SQL ?

Comment: then why are you mapping it to String ?

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: @ShadowRay i can't insert to DB when i let the DATESORTIE field empty

Comment: Date sorite shouldn't be empty String ,just make a check if it is `''`et to `null`.

Comment: @ShadowRay i should insert DATESORTIE as String (i can't change the dateSortie in the Employe.java to Date)

Answer (score 1):

Table `EMPLOYE` , column `DATESORTIE` contains an empty string `''`, change it to `null` and try again.

Comment: i should let the date field like that [IMG](http://pasteboard.co/2BUqy41z.png) and it should be stored as null

Comment: oui tu peux le faire , il suffit juste de le marker en tant que date : 
 et dans ton input met cette valeur en tant que `placeholder`

Comment: je dois la mettre en tant que string, pour cela je cherche une solution avec String